# "a step down" in French

Tags: expressions, traduction

How do you translate "step down" to French. The meaning I am looking for is:

> London is not a step down from Paris

or

> The Senate is not a step down from governorship

Does *"une etape en bas"* make sense? or is there some other expression which is more common?

Comment: Moi je le trouve pas mal ton "*une étape en bas*". Il y a de l'idée que je reprends pour dire un poil plus idiomatiquement : ***Un cran en dessous***

Comment: @aCOSwt Oui, ça peut faire, réponds, vas-y. On utilise aussi la comparaison. Mais il faut aussi lui dire que step ne se traduit en français par étape que quand ça a le sens de stage. Mener une expérience étape par étape. Carry an experiment step by step.

Comment: @Laure : *"Réponds, vas-y*"... C'est SI j'veux! :-P : Bon...blague dans le coin.. on a tout dit là. *Ite missa est* quoi.

Comment: @Laure : Comment tu dis ? Un commentaire c'est quand même *un cran en dessous d'une réponse* ? Parce que *la réponse c'est l'étape d'après* ?

Comment: @aCOSwt "Don't answer in comments" :-) De plus je conseillerais plutôt "blague à part" que "blague dans le coin" qui n'est pas idiomatique, du moins là où je suis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Does "une étape en bas" make sense?

> *Londres n'est pas une étape en bas de Paris.*

won't be understood. *Step* in the expression "to step down" literally translates to *marche (d'escalier)* giving *descendre une marche*, i.e. *renoncer à / quitter une place élevée*. On the other hand, *une étape* is more like a "stage" in the *Tour de France*.

2. or is there some other expression which is more common?

If you want to stay close to the image:

> *Londres n'est pas **le marchepied** de Paris.*

Alternatives can be:

> *Londres n'est pas **inférieure** à Paris.*
>
> *Londres n'est pas **au dessous** de Paris.*

About your second example, I would say:

> *Être sénateur n'est pas **moins considéré** qu'être gouverneur*

Comment: "marchepied" would mean that you start with Paris and then upgrade to London.

Comment: @MathieuBouville C'est le contraire. La métaphore est ici le marchepied d'un carosse ou d'un train. Le marchepied (Londres) servirait donc ici d'accessoire facilitant la montée vers la destination (Paris).

Answer (score 1):

For  the first sentence  I'd trust to DeepL, but in supposing that the meaning is literal (merely physical distance). However, I'd modify what DeepL comes up with on the count of a quasi missing form in the negative.

- Londres n'est **pas une ville à deux pas de** Paris. (*"pas à deux pas de" would be very unusual ([ref.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0+deux+pas+de%2Cpas+%C3%A0+deux+pas+de&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20deux%20pas%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpas%20%C3%A0%20deux%20pas%20de%3B%2Cc0)*))

If this first sentence were taken figuratively I'd use a more colourful but tempting vocabulary.

- Londres n'est pas une **version bon marché de** Paris.
- Londres n'est pas une cité qui n'aurait **que des choses à envier à** Paris.
- Londres n'est pas un Paris **au rabais**.

For the second sentence, in which necessarily "a step down" has to be taken figuratively, I'd be somewhat more specific than is the English, as in French that specificity seems rather usual.

- Le Sénat n'est pas **un organe de gouvernement dont le pouvoir serait  à deux doigts près celui d'un** poste de gouverneur. (*Same remark as above ([ref.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0+deux+doigts+de%2Cpas+%C3%A0+deux+doigts+de&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20deux%20doigts%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpas%20%C3%A0%20deux%20doigts%20de%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20deux%20doigts%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpas%20%C3%A0%20deux%20doigts%20de%3B%2Cc0))*)

Notice that according to the assumption made, the word used ("pas" and "doigts") are not interchangeable.

Note : As told in the commentaries "étape" would not do ; in fact, neither would "stage" do for these translations.

Comment: Un locuteur natif de l'anglais [comprendra](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52206166#52206166) « not worse than » et à mon avis (mais ce n'est pas le sujet du site) on ne peut pas interpréter cette locution verbale en termes de distance. Il s'ensuit que DeepL se trompe en employant _pas à 1/2 pas_ (tout à fait usuel en passant). Le but n'est pas de prendre ta réponse en défaut mais bien d'illustrer que les robots se plantent (encore) et qu'il s'avère imprudent de trop faire confiance à ces outils sans vérifier soit sur ELU/ELL, ou en demandant plus de contexte au demandeur.